# SiS update problem

Tags: upgrade

My problem:

I've had Lubuntu and Windows XP dual boot for a long time. 
After some XP updates, it did something with the Linux boot such that I couldn't dual boot.

I finally got in and updated Lubuntu and completely removed Windows.
My Sis video wont let me in now: 
    Screen's Frequency Out of Range

I tried many solutions that did not work: removing `#` from `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640*400` worked for three startups, but failed on the fourth. The Live CD works fine until installed.
I give up and tried slitaz 4 and slitaz 3 and neither worked, but both work fine on my other laptop.
I burnt Salix 13.37 (lxde-been wanting to try it anyhow) and got

```
kernel panic!
```

My USB Xpud and Browser Linux 501 boot I don't know how to install Xpud if I would want to for this is a desktop. Browser Linux 501 seemed to have issues on Live USB that don't happen on mini laptop so didn't try install.  other OS like DSL etc. I know don't want. So I dug out Ubuntu 9.10 and it works fine. I know its unsupported, but every upgrade I try SiS video fails! I could live with 9.10 except even the best from `/old-releases` is Firefox 3.6.17

How/where/could FireFox 5.0.1 work on Ubuntu 9.10 or will it need packages I cant install? (I'm pretty sure anything past Firefox 5.0.1 wont work in 9.10 - but didn't 9.10 have chromium ? I don't see it)

This is a northbridge and southbridge chipset (SiS741GX/SiS964L) with an overclocked Sempron.
Any ideas on how to upgrade without changing any of the SiS video drivers in 9.10 that work great to a newer Ubuntu or a way to roll back to them before restarting would work?

Answer (score 1):

I found a old copy of firefox-5.0.1.tar.bz2 
HERE http://www.oldapps.com/linux/firefox.php?old_firefox=103
After download
Right-click the file (firefox-5.0.1.tar.bz2) and choose Extract Here (desktop)
You will now have a new folder on your desktop called Firefox.
 
Rename it to Firefox-5.0.1
Open a terminal window (just this once) and type sudo nautilus – this will launch your file browser with root privileges
Navigate to File System -> usr -> lib ( /usr/lib/ ) and copy the folder Firefox-5.0.1 into this directory
Open the folder Firefox-5.0.1 and find the file called Firefox.
Right click and Make Link. It creates a file called Link to Firefox
Cut and paste this link to File System -> usr -> bin ( /usr/bin/ )
There is already a link called firefox so rename that to firefox.old (if there isn’t, don’t worry), rename your new Link to Firefox (Link to Firefox) to just firefox  !

you will not lose any bookmarks or settings from your current browser. But backup just in case.

Updates now have a box in Firefox 5.0.1 Preferences - 
And help / about firefox - now has a Check For Updates button 
I checked and then double checked requirements and updated to 12 Fine. 
Checked For Updates again and now running Firefox 16.0.1 on Ubuntu 9.10 cool

**I still have the SiS video update problem** 
installed the Lubuntu Desktop to feel at home
You can install software or upgrade from old unsupported release like 9.10 by
editing /etc/apt/sources.list and change archive.ubuntu.com to old-releases.ubuntu.com

**Would anybody know if its possible to mix Precise Pangolin & Karmic Koala sources.lists ?** maybe a dumb question but I'm in the unknown I tried all the solutions for SiS I could find and nothing works past 9.10 
the next Update gives me a Frequency Out of Range on logout THAT ISNT GOOD! 
but its not on login, I didnt compare the files to that 10.04.3 I wasnt thinking to at the time
Here are the 9.10 packages I working for me
xserver-xorg-video-sis  1:0.10.1-2
xserver-xorg-video-sisusb 1:0.9.1-1